# if condition in asynchronous socket programming

Tags: sockets

How can I use if condition in asynchronous socket programming.

For example if client sends "hello" then server response is "hi" and if client send "how r u" then server send "i am fine".
I have this code and I am trying to do that, but it does not work.
Please tell where i need to change my code.
Thanks in Advance
Here is server code

public class StateObject
        {
            public Socket workSocket = null;

```
        public const int BufferSize = 1024;

        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];

        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    }
    public class AsynchronousSocketListener
    {

        public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public AsynchronousSocketListener()
        {

        }

        public static void StartListening()
        {
            byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());

            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];

            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8888);

            Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            try
            {

                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);

                listener.Listen(100);

                while (true)
                {
                    allDone.Reset();

                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");

                    listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),listener);

                    allDone.WaitOne();

                }



            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

            }



            Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");

            Console.Read();

        }



        public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            allDone.Set();

            Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

            StateObject state = new StateObject();

            state.workSocket = handler;

            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);

        }

        public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {

            String content = String.Empty;

            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;

            Socket handler = state.workSocket;

            int bytesRead  = handler.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
           {
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                content = state.sb.ToString();

                if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                {
                    if (content == "hello")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(content);
                        Send(handler, content);
                    }
                    else if (content == "How r u")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(content);
                        Send2(handler, content);
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);

                }


            }

        }

        private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
        {
            data = "Hi";

            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);

        }


        private static void Send2(Socket handler, String data)
        {
            data = "fine";

            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);

        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {

            try
            {
                Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);

                Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);     

                 handler.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

            }

        }

        public static int Main(String[] args)
        {

            StartListening();

            return 0;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`content == "How r u"` and `content == "hello"` check the object equality by comparing there references. `content` and your const strings are not in the same memory (not the same objects).

To compare there content call `content.compareTo("How r u")==0`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I just have to put < eof > at the end of 'hello' like "hello< eof >" and same to how r u. Its work now.